# Array count error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have two methods. From the first method I am sending an array to the second method. In my first method [array count] value is 2. But in the seconf method the value is 1. But it should be the same in both method. I know its a silly mistake. But I dont understand exactly where I have done the mistake.

First method:

```
-(void)uploadOverlayManually: (NSMutableArray *)path{

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSLog(@"Array count #1: %d",[path count]);

for (int i =0; i < [path count]; i++) {

    imagePath = [path objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *infoPath = [[imagePath stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"info"];
    NSData *infoData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:infoPath];

    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:infoData];
    MediaInformation *currentInfo = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"info"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    UIImage *baseImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    NSData *data = [root addImageOverlay:baseImage withInfo:currentInfo andPath:imagePath];

    [data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    fileUpload = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [fileUpload addObject:imagePath];

}

[self upload:fileUpload];
```

}

Second method:

```
-(void)upload:(NSArray*)filePaths{

if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {

    [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:root]; //root
}

NSLog(@"Array count #2: %d",[filePaths count]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
fileUpload = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

inside your loop recreates the array.

It should be before the loop so you add an object on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate a new array on each loop so it can always be just 1

To achieve the intended behavior use (moved instantiation out of the loop):

```
-(void)uploadOverlayManually: (NSMutableArray *)path{

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSLog(@"Array count #1: %d",[path count]);

fileUpload = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i =0; i < [path count]; i++) {

    imagePath = [path objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *infoPath = [[imagePath stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"info"];
    NSData *infoData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:infoPath];

    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:infoData];
    MediaInformation *currentInfo = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"info"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    UIImage *baseImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    NSData *data = [root addImageOverlay:baseImage withInfo:currentInfo andPath:imagePath];

    [data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    [fileUpload addObject:imagePath];

}

[self upload:fileUpload];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating Array inside of a loop please allocate it in viewDidLoad or in any function that only called once.